# Access fragment from list adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

Inside my activity I have 3 tags. TabFrag A, TabFrag B and TabFrag C.

TabFragB is a list view. Each View having a button inside it.

When I press that button a new fragment should replace the current view.

However, I am getting a java null point error.

CODE: TabFrag B.

```
public class TabDelta extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener 
{
private Fragment mFragment;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{  
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, container, false);

    ListView tabbList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ListConsole);
    Adapter_TabBList a_tabbList = new Adapter_TabBList(getActivity(),gs.Members,mFragment);
    deltaList.setAdapter(a_tabbList);

    return view;        
}   

public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
{
    mFragment = new TabDelta();     
    ft.add(R.id.LLfragmentconsole, mFragment);
    ft.attach(mFragment);
}
```

}

CODE ADAPTER(Adapter_TabBList):

```
public class Adapter_TabBList extends ArrayAdapter<Member> 
{
private final FragmentActivity context;
private final ArrayList<Member> values;
//private final String tag;
Fragment f;

GlobalState gs;

public Adapter_TabBList(FragmentActivity context, ArrayList<Member> values,Fragment f) 
{
    super(context, R.layout.lr_tabb, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
    this.gs = (GlobalState) context.getApplication();   
    //this.tag = tag;
    this.f = f;
}
```

OnCLICK LISTNER INSIDE ADAPTER:

```
holder.add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            FragmentManager fm = context.getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.addToBackStack(f.getTag()); //LINE 116
            ft.hide(f);
            //ft.addToBackStack(tag);   
            //ft.hide(fm.findFragmentById(tag));            
            ft.add(R.id.LLfragmentconsole,new addEvent(), "NEW_EVENT");   
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
```

LOGCAT:

```
01-10 10:09:40.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1387): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 10:09:40.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1387): Process: com.ani.tf, PID: 1387
01-10 10:09:40.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1387): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-10 10:09:40.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1387): at com.ani.tf.Adapter_TabBList$1.onClick(Adapter_TabBList.java:116)
```

ERROR is at ft.addToBackStack(f.getTag())

I donot want to go for replace fragment command as I want on back press to return to TabFragB.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: where is ft declared and initialized in the fragment TabDelta?

Comment: It is inside ontabselected module

Comment: post the stacktrace and indicate which line causes `NullPointerException`?

Comment: so is f null or f.getTag()?

Comment: ft.addToBackStack(f.getTag()) this where i am getting error

Comment: also, instead of passing the Fragment into the adapter you should be using a Listener to pass it back to the fragment. Listener can expose a method along the lines of onAddClicked which is implemented in your fragment. Fragment registers as a listener on the adapter.

Comment: hmmm...good idea...never tried that for an adapter..let me give it  a try